# Кодировать в base64

Tags: c#, powershell

Есть байтовый массив byte[] File.
Мне надо закодировать в base64, я делаю это так

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(File);
```

и потом обратно раскодировать, но уже декодирую в powershell, вот так

```
$DataDecoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('s'))
```

И у меня появляется откуда-то символ "?" в самом начале файла в первой строке. Пробовал разные кодировки указывать и UTF8(один знак ? в начале) и ASCII(три знака ??? в начале) и Unicode (все вообще в знаках ?).
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: вы делаете все верно. А что вы ожидаете увидеть, исходный массив байт это некая строка в какой-то кодировке?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Исходная строка это скрипт powershell, например Script.ps1, и даже если там просто написано "Get-service winrm", то после этой операции кодирования-декодирования там оказывается "?Get-service winrm"

Comment: `File` считывается из файла сразу как массив байтов? Методом типа `File.ReadAllBytes`? Подозреваю, что это [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у меня вообще задача считать этот файл кусками (допустим по 1кб), потом преобразовать в base64 этот кусок, затем обратно и записать в другой файл на удаленном компе...честно говоря, возможно я накосячил со считыванием файла, сейчас проверяю